# Opencart 3 new Product Submitted Data

Tags: php, jquery, opencart

I filled addProduct form input's automatically with jQuery

**Example:**

```
$("#input-price").val("15"); //(not necessary)
$("#input-name1").val("Product Name"); //(necessary)
$("#input-meta-title1").val("Meta title"); //(necessary)
$(".note-editable").val("Description");  //(not necessary)
```

When I post the form, Opencart return "Success" but necessary inputs saved but unnecessary field is empty.That's mean unnecessary field didn't save

If I fill all inputs from manually, every inputs has been saved.
I don't understand why?

Comment: I tested your code and it works. I also added `$("#input-model").val("Product Model"); //(necessary)`, how do you post the form?

Comment: I just click the save button

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: I run this code in Chrome extension.Could this be the reason?

Comment: I wrote this code in browser console.But same problem here.Example I add description like this : $(".note-editable").html("<h1>Hello World!</h1>"); or I add thumb image like this : $("#thumb-image >img").attr("src","imageurl"); Is that true?